# How i can change the "standard" install type by Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

i have three types in my Inno Setup script.
Looks like that:

Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation"
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

If i build the installler now the "standard" type is full but i want that the first choice is "compact".
I didn't find anything in the documantation of Inno Setup, but maybe i had the wrong keywords...

How i can realize that?

Thanks for your help
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
that's my solution:

In the example projects, the order of Types select the default value.
thanks mirtheil for that fast and correct answer.

But that didn't work in my custom project. So now i changed the description of the Items.
my code was looking like this:

```
[Types]
Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation"
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom
```

My default Item was everytime "full". So i changed the description to that:

```
[Types]
Name: "compact"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "full"; Description: "Compact installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom
```

and changed the type flags from my Components so that "full" is "compact" and "compact" is "full".

a little bit confusing and not very nice, but i found no other solution.

Answer (score 8):

Based on some limited testing, the order of the `[Types]` section will determine which type will be selected by default.  Given this list:

```
[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom
```

The "Full installation" type will be first in the list. If you want "Compact installation" first, you should change it to:

```
[Types]
Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation"
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom
```

So that the one you want to be the default is first in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.

That was my first idea too, but that didn't works for me in Version 5.5.9(a). 

I make some tests, it works for me in the "Components" example project but not in my personal installer. Strange :S